# Is there something you can put in your code which starts an interactive interpreter (in python)

Tags: python, debugging, interactive

The idea is to be able to run the code normally, except it will start an interactive interpreter in the given scope when it gets to a particular method call. Sort of like stopping at a breakpoint to run code.

Ideally, if you are already in an interpreter like ipython, it would return to that interpreter, except with access the current scope in addition to the interpreter scope.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [code](http://docs.python.org/library/code.html) module.

Here's an example:

```
import code
a = 1
b = 2
code.interact(local=locals())
```

Output:

```
Python 2.7 (r27:82500, Nov 10 2010, 22:46:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want [`code`](http://docs.python.org/library/code.html).

Comment: Lots of people come to StackOverflow because they want code. Just an observation :-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a REPL as you get from running python (without a script file) or from ipython, do you want to start a [debugger](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html)?

```
def example(a, b, c):
  a.apple(b.blah() + c)

  import pdb
  pdb.set_trace()

  c.continuing_on()
  while inspecting(this.code()) in the_debugger:
    print "hooray"
```

You can execute arbitrary code from pdb, but it also has handy commands to inspect while continuing to run the existing code.